# Voltage variation in the output of Differential Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement, differential-amplifier

[image: Low side current sensing differential amplifier]

I am working in low side current sensing differential amplifier circuit. VA is connected to ground and resistance R2 is also connected to ground but both the grounds are not same then there is voltage variation in VOUT. When I short both the ground and connected to one ground then the voltage variation is very less. I want to know Why there is a voltage variation when there is different ground?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on R tolerances mainly then  the R ratio tolerances to avoid Common mode gain interfering with Differential gain.

It is more accurate to use an INA with an STP cable if there is noise.

- But be sure the Vcm is in the range of the amplifier.

I can't say much more without full design expectations, layout and test results.